# Cypress headless - no loaders are configured to process png files

Tags: reactjs, webpack, cypress

I am trying to run cypress test cases headless using cmd command

```
npx cypress run
```

But it gives me below error -
[image]

Do I need to install any dependency for this to load.
Even css files are not getting loaded.

Note : I haven't installed webpack or any other dependency. Only cypress is installed additionally.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to extend the webpack configuration used by cypress to handle the files you would like to load. You can find an example [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/develop/npm/webpack-preprocessor/examples/react-app/cypress/plugins/index.js)

Below I've modified the example to work with cypress 10.

```
// cypress.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress';
import findWebpack from 'find-webpack';
import webpackPreprocessor from '@cypress/webpack-preprocessor';

const webpackOptions = findWebpack.getWebpackOptions();
const options = {
  webpackOptions,
  watchOptions: {},
};

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on) {
      // implement node event listeners here
      // on('file:preprocessor', webpack(options));
      // use a module that carefully removes only plugins
      // that we found to be breaking the bundling
      // https://github.com/bahmutov/find-webpack
      const cleanOptions = {
        reactScripts: true,
      };

      findWebpack.cleanForCypress(cleanOptions, webpackOptions);
      on('file:preprocessor', webpackPreprocessor(options));
    },
    specPattern: 'src/**/*.cy.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
  },
});
```